# ML.NET adding new data to existing model

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I am using the latest ML.NET samples. I have generated a model running the ImageClassificationTraining example.

I only have the images temporarily so I need to keep adding new images, as I do not have the original images I can't rebuild the whole model from scratch.

Is it possible to retrain with new data only? I cannot find any solutions in the MS docs.